# Is it possible to declare multiple @ViewChild() elements and how can I access them?

Tags: angular

I have this template:

```
<ion-content no-bounce>
  <ion-nav  #pageView class="no-scroll"></ion-nav>
</ion-content>

 <ion-grid #menu class="menu" (swipe)="swipeEvent($event)"> 
 </ion-grid>
```

What I want is to access to the DOM element #menu and #pageView I'm trying to do that with:

@ViewChild('menu')     menu     : ElementRef;

@ViewChild('pageView') pageView : ElementRef;

But it seems those elements are undefined because when I console.log(this.menu, this.pageView) log throws undefined. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Maybe because HTML is not prepared yet? Try to console in `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: I try it but it still throwing undefined

Comment: Sorry @localStanger yes you have the reason, I was trying to acces to the elements on the constructor :( instead ngAfterViewInit() thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: Great! Your welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use angular lifecycle to get rid of this issue
To use your viewchild variable you have to use ngAfterViewInit, then only that views will be available.

i.e

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  console.log(this.menu, this.pageView) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer